# L'Ecuyer's MRG32k3a random number generator in CUDA C?

Tags: random, cuda, prng

I am facing trouble implementing this. I want to run some monte carlo simulations on gpu cluster and require the Random Number Generator to work for it. I want to print the random numbers generated. Could someone please explain with an example? I am working in unix.

Thanks!

Comment: What, specifically, are you stuck on?

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Actually, I am not much of a coder and more of a Mathematics/Statistics person. I haven't worked with CUDA before. I am working on this project for which I require the code for random number generation using mrg32k3a generator. How can I get a working code for that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It's available since CUDA 4.1 with [cuRAND library](http://developer.nvidia.com/curand) .